# How to add to a textbox the red line (like bad spelling in Word)?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-2.0

How can we produce the effect of the red line under a bad spelling word like the image below :

[alt text http://img505.imageshack.us/img505/7253/options285x395rg9.th.png](http://img505.imageshack.us/img505/7253/options285x395rg9.th.png)

**Update**

I do not want to use Google or whatever spell program. I would like to know how to create the effect of the red line.

Comment: FYI - Firefox and Chrome do it automatically for you. No site interaction necessary.

Comment: Are you asking how to determine if a word is misspelled?

Or are you asking how to draw a wavy red line under a word?

Comment: Was there supposed to be an image in that question? I'm not seeing one?

Comment: I was wondering if it's possible to recreate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this using a [RichTextBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.richtextbox?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)  control, which will allow you to set the underline style and underline color on any portion of text.

And here's an [example](https://web.archive.org/web/20200803184227/http://geekswithblogs.net/pvidler/archive/2003/10/15/188.aspx) doing exactly what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

use google's spellchecker

http://www.asp101.com/articles/jeremy/googlespell/default.asp

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://www.codedblog.com/2007/09/17/owner-drawing-a-windowsforms-textbox/) shows how to owner-draw a TextBox to draw the wavy red line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use rich edit control's properties and methods to do the drawing of the wavy lines. For more information visit this site: http://geekswithblogs.net/pvidler/archive/2003/10/15/188.aspx