# How to draw red wavy line under words in RichTextBox c# winform

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

How to draw red wavy line under words in **RichTextBox c# winform** as normally seen in spelling errors( as in MS Word)? I don't want to use underline feature of RichTextBox

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179423/how-to-add-to-a-textbox-the-red-line-like-bad-spelling-in-word

Answer (score 7):

`\ulwave` should underline text with a wave. here is a list of RTF format: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140283(v=office.10).aspx#rtfspec_fontcharformat

remember to set the underline to none after with: `\ulnone`

Comment: Calling it `RTF commands` is not exact, should be `RTF syntax`.

Comment: or format, but it doesn't matter

Comment: What is the correct Syntax? `<ulwave>`? Or is it something else?

Comment: It's quite simple, before the text just add `\ulwave` and after the text `\ulnone`